# How to overwrite hardcoded array values in my Bash source file

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I set an array with static values in the code of my script. It basically handles strings and I want to remove some of theses values.

Somehow I didn't find any way to overwrite values of the array in the code of my script.

I can remove values but just in the lifetime of my script. When the script ends, my array is reset to the hardcoded values.

How can I do this?

Comment: Of course, they will be back if your script that removed them ends. They are written in this file after all. So you need to manipulate and change the actual content of the file. Maybe with awk or sed.

Comment: The *hardcoded values* are in the source code. Changing the value at runtime does not edit the source code, so when your script is stopped and then started, the hardcoded values are stil in the source and still in the array. Edit the script code if you want them changed permanently.

Comment: "When the script ends, my array is reset to the hardcoded values." -- expand on this: _where_ is the array defined? In your .bashrc or a similar dot file? Be aware that child processes **cannot** alter the environment of the parent process, so you might want to `source` the script instead of executing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can persist, save a modified array state for next runs of your script this way:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

default_fruits=( 'apricot' 'banana' 'cocoa' )

# Try to restore saved fruits array from saved_fruits.sh
if ! . saved_fruits.sh
# if not available, use the default fruits
then fruits=( "${default_fruits[@]}" )
fi

# Print fruits array that will be different after first run
printf 'Fruits:\n'
printf '%s\n' "${fruits[@]}"

# Change the fruits array at run-time

fruits[1]='blueberry'

# Save the array to recover it next time
declare -p fruits >saved_fruits.sh
```

First time running this script:

```
apricot
banana
cocoa
```

Subsequent runs will output:

```
apricot
blueberry
cocoa
```